# Why does it create new variable instead of reporting an error?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
   let answer: SomeType = new SomeType();
   ...some code...
   if(something)
   {
       let answer = new SomeType();
   }
```

In the above code using "let" inside the "if" was a mistake and I would expect Typescript to report it as an error. Instead, Typescript compiled this line to Java script as:
        var answer_1 = new SomeType();
basically generated a new variable by its own.

Is this expected behavior? I think it's a bug. This is why I'm using let instead of var If expected behavior, is there a compiler option that would report this as an error?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017

Thanks

Comment: That's explicitly what the `let` keyword does. 
 https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/let.html

Answer (score 1):

> Is this expected behavior?

Yes.

It's why `let` is different then `var`. You can read more about [the difference between var and let in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html).

Excerpt:

> When a variable is declared using let, it uses what some call lexical-scoping or block-scoping. Unlike variables declared with var whose scopes leak out to their containing function, block-scoped variables are not visible outside of their nearest containing block or for-loop.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference between let and var and this is why I choose let instead of using var. The point is that if there is a "let answer" definition in an outer block, trying to define again "let answer" in an inner block is a syntax error and should be reported as such. This is what C# compiler does. Typescript shouldn't be trying to "solve" the problem by simply creating a variable with a different name in the inner block. This isn't solving anything, on the contrary, it's just hiding a real bug.

Comment: Comparing technology is not a valid reason to assume something should happen in one of them.  Let is does exactly what its suppose to, and the typescript compiler is doing what the ecmascript language specifies.

Answer (score 0):

The tslint no-shadowed-variable rule does what I was looking for.